# Call to a member function getRealPath() on string while sending an email

Tags: laravel

Call to a member function `getRealPath()` on string error occurs while sending an email.

**Controller**

```
public function store(CareerRequest $request)
{
    $requestData = $request->all();

    $filenameWithExt = $request->file('resume')->getClientOriginalName();
    $filename = pathinfo($filenameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
    $extension = $request->file('resume')->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $fileNameToStore = $filename.'_'.time().'.'.$extension;
    $request->file('resume')->storeAs('candidateResume', $fileNameToStore);    
    $requestData["resume"] =$fileNameToStore ;

    Career::create($requestData);

    return redirect()->back();
}
```

**Mailable**

```
class CareerMail extends Mailable
{
    public $data;

    public function __construct($data)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    public function build()
    {
        return $this->subject('Career - '. $this->data->subject)

                    ->view('emails.career')
                    ->attach($this->data['resume']->getRealPath(),
                [
                    'as' => $this->data['resume']->getClientOriginalName(),
                    'mime' => $this->data['resume']->getClientMimeType(),
                ]);
    }
}
```

**Error on line**

```
->attach($this->data['resume']->getRealPath(),
```

Comment: try to call `dd($this->data['resume'])` ,  this data resume is string , while what you expected is an File object

Comment: can you please answer the code?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use function `getRealPath()` on your $fileNameToStore, which is a string : `$filename.'_'.time().'.'.$extension`.

`getRealPath()` will only work on `$request()->file('resume')->getRealPath()`.

If you want to get the information of your file, you should use Uploaded file instance instead or get the file instance you stored.