# How to display the path of the file where it uploaded in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

My controller:

```
public function store(CareerRequest $request) 
{
    $filenameWithExt = $request->file('resume')->getClientOriginalName();
    $filename = pathinfo($filenameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
    $extension = $request->file('resume')->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $fileNameToStore = $filename.'_'.time().'.'.$extension;
    $request->file('resume')->storeAs('resume', $fileNameToStore);
    $requestData["resume"] =$fileNameToStore ;

    Career::create($request->all());
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

My model:

```
class Career extends Model 
{
    protected $table = 'career';
    protected $primaryKey = 'career_id';

    public $fillable = ['username', 'email', 'phone', 'apply', 'resume'];

    public function getUrlAttribute(): string
    {
        return asset('upload/resume/'.$this->attributes['resume']);
    }
}
```

CareerMail:
class CareerMail extends Mailable
{

```
public $data;

public function __construct($data)

{
    $this->data = $data;
}

public function build()

{
    return $this->subject('Career - ' . $this->data->subject)

        ->view('emails.career')
        ->attach(
            $this->data['resume']->getRealPath(),
            [
                'as' => $this->data['resume']->getClientOriginalName(),
                'mime' => $this->data['resume']->getClientMimeType(),
            ]
        );
}
```

}

I have a form, when I submit the form the details goes to dashboard. And from dashboard I want to download the resume file, which has been uploaded.

Comment: Someone else has [already answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75332394/248567) your follow up edit on this question.

Answer (score 1):

First of all as mentioned in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/filesystem#the-public-disk):

> To make these files accessible from the web, you should create a symbolic link from public/storage to storage/app/public.

Use this command if you haven't before:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

After that you are missing `resume` name you created. You have to pass it to your `create()` method:

```
Career::create(array_merge($request->all(), ['resume' => $fileNameToStore]));
```

Then just change the URL:

```
public function getUrlAttribute(): string
{
    return asset('storage/resume/'.$this->resume);
}
```

Now simply just:

```
echo $career->url;
```

Comment: @dev-patil Im pretty sure it works? Did you try? Let me know!

Answer (score 0):

In your code, it looks like you are storing the uploaded file in the "resume" directory within the "upload" directory. To display the path of the file where it was uploaded, you can use the `getUrlAttribute` method in your `Career` model.

The `getUrlAttribute` method returns the URL of the file by concatenating the asset function with the path to the "resume" directory and the filename.

To display the path of the file where it was uploaded, you can call the `getUrlAttribute` method on the `Career` model instance that represents the uploaded file. For example:

```php
$career = Career::find($id);
$path = $career->url;
```

The `$path` variable will contain the URL of the uploaded file, which includes the path to the "resume" directory and the filename. Note that the path returned by the `getUrlAttribute` method is relative to the server root, not the file system path.